# drupal7 adding info to page with hook_node_view

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

very new to Drupal. I am trying to add a simple "hello world" string to a drupal page when it loads using hook_node_view. My code so far:

```
function myModule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full' && $node->type == 'page') {
        $node->content['myText'] = array(
            '#markup' => '<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>',
        );
    }
}
```

From my understanding, when the page is loading, each node will call hook_node_view and if the node type is page if should add my hello world string to the end of its text. I'm sure this understanding is completely wrong but I'm unsure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Eventually, hello world will be dynamic content and I want it to print to the top of every drupal page.

Thanks!

Comment: can you add dpm($view_mode) and dpm($node->type == 'page') and check if you pass your conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **weight**

```
function myModule_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {
    if ($view_mode == 'full' && $node->type == 'page') {
        $node->content['myText'] = array(
            '#markup' => '<h1>HELLO WORLD</h1>',
            '#weight' => -1 // negative will brings to the top
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: that worked thanks! Does it set the default weight so that it doesn't appear at all? Do positive weights force it to the bottom of the page?